# Employee File Search

Tags: c#

I write a file and input the First Name, Last Name, Employee Id, Address and Zip Code then Save, Then if you go to search and input the zip code the file of the same zip code will show,but when I input the zip code the file will not show. i think my code is having a problem can you help me with this.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlRead.Location = pnlWrite.Location;
            pnlSearch.Location = pnlWrite.Location;
            pnlWrite.BringToFront();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Employee.txt", string.Empty);
        }

        private void writeToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlWrite.BringToFront();
        }

        private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnSave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string EmployeeData;
            listRead.Items.Clear();

            EmployeeData = txtFirstName.Text + "\n" + txtLastName.Text + "\n"
                + txtID.Text + "\n" + txtAddress.Text + "\n" + txtZipCode.Text + "\n\n";
            File.AppendAllText("Employee.txt", EmployeeData);
            txtFirstName.Clear();
            txtLastName.Clear();
            txtID.Clear();
            txtAddress.Clear();
            txtZipCode.Clear();
            txtFirstName.Focus();
            listRead.Items.Clear();

        }

        private void readToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlRead.BringToFront();
            try
            {
                string[] EmployeeData = File.ReadAllLines("Employee.txt");
                listRead.Items.AddRange(EmployeeData);
                listRead.ClearSelected();    
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
            }
        }

        private void searchToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlSearch.BringToFront();
        }

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlRead.BringToFront();
            listRead.Items.Clear();

            try
            {
                string[] EmployeeData = File.ReadAllLines("Employee.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < EmployeeData.Length; i += 2)
                {
                    if (EmployeeData[i] == txtSearch.Text)
                    {
                        listRead.Items.Add(EmployeeData[i]);
                        listRead.Items.Add(EmployeeData[i + 1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok let me try, its functioning well but the zip code will only show the other will not

Comment: What should I put then. can you suggest some. im too weak with the for loop statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop, if you find the match with the zip code you add just that line and the following one (with the risk to go out of bounds)

There is a simple way to add every line in your array to the Items collection

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlRead.BringToFront();
    listRead.Items.Clear();

    try
    {
        string[] EmployeeData = File.ReadAllLines("Employee.txt");
        if(EmployeeData.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
            listRead.Items.AddRange(EmployeeData);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File or path not found or invalid.");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do not stop to study how the for loop works. While the Framework contains many useful methods that remove the need of an explicit for loop you will need it for many tasks.

Comment: Hello one's again sir Steve, I have a problem if I write again another info with not the same zip code, the previous info will also show

Comment: What you are trying to search is known as a 'record', a basic concept of database systems. A text file is not the best choice to act as a database. I suggest you to write all your info about an employee in a single line, separating each piece of information with a semicolon. Then you can read back all the lines in your file, split each line at the semicolon creating your array and then examine just the zip code of that line. This is known as CSV Text file and there are many examples how to read /write them. I suggest to post a new question with this problem so more users can help

Comment: And if you want to try by yourself, then search about two methods of the string class: string.Join and string.Split

Comment: yes Im trying , so I could learn, if It is so difficult I will post for a help. ill read some information about those string.Join and string.Split